# How can I filter the values in a JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

When I get data from API it returns me like below JSON (**response**)

```
{
   "brand": "",
   "item": [
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": ""
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      }
   ]
}
```

My expectations:
If item.url == "" then the element will be removed immediately.

After deleting:

```
{
   "brand": "",
   "item": [
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      },
      {
         "name": "ABC",
         "url": "https..."
      }
   ]
}
```

```
struct DataDetail {
    var brand:Brand
    var items: [Item]
    
    struct Brand {
        let title: String?
        let image: URL?
    }
    
    public struct Item {
        let name: String
        let url: URL?
    }
}
```

```
var dataDetail1: DataDetail

fetchAPI { [weak self] response in
    self.dataDetail1 = response
}
```

How can I filter the (**response**) to display as expected? If item.url == "" then the element will be removed immediately.

Comment: I notice now that none of your types conforms to Codable and that the json sample with "" for brand looks strange. How do you currently convert the json to your custom types?

Comment: Why not update both samples? And please answer my question.

Comment: You can understand simply that: I want to remove 1 element in item (if item.url is empty)

Comment: `self.dataDetail1 = DataDetail(brand: response.brand, items: response.items.filter { DoTheFilterHere })`, now, since `url` is an optional, is it nil?

Comment: @Larme it's optional, if it is nil it will be removed from the element in item

Comment: Then `DoTheFilterHere` is `$0.url != nil`? Or I don't understand the test you want to do. because empty string isn't a valid `URL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When decoding into your type you can add a custom init to remove empty strings and null.

```
struct Brand: Codable {
    let brand: String
    var item: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brand
        case item
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        brand = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .brand)
        var items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: .item)
        items = items.filter { $0.url != nil } //remove nil 
        items.removeAll { $0.url!.isEmpty } //remove empty
        item = items
    }
}
```